# Projection of future traffic for major programming languages

Tags: discussion, statistics, graphs

I have found from around 2017 or 2018, the following graph made by Stack Overflow:

[image: projection traffic]

Where could I find a more recent version?

I have looked at 2021 Developer Survey and didn't see anything related (but on the other hand, it's not related to a survey but rather statistics from the website).

Comment: This is *possibly* more relevant to Stack Overflow's per-site meta?

Comment: @bobble I thought questions related to [the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/06/incredible-growth-python/) could be posted here.

Comment: The close review banner says: "Not suitable for this site - Do not use this close reason for questions that relate to multiple sites, even if they focus on a specific site.", and the tag is on-topic:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/blog/info

Comment: This is similar to, but quite the same as, the data available on [the Stack Overflow Trends page](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=python%2Cjavascript%2Cjava%2Cc%23%2Cphp%2Cc%2B%2B) ([image version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGACb.png)). Note, however, that the trends page measures "*% of Stack Overflow **questions** that month*" rather than question views.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if the predictions actually came true. In SEDE only total question views are stored, so to recreate the plot we would need to have SEDE databases from different times. In absence of this only staff can produce this.